# Formatar uma string que o matcher encontrou

Tags: java

Estou utilizando matcher para pegar padrões diferentes de hora porém quando for escrever a mesma gostaria que ela fosse escrita no formato correto, tentei utilizar SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm:ss"), porém não funcionou.

Por exemplo: O matcher encontrou 17:4441 no texto. Preciso que de alguma forma quando eu for reescrever essa String ele retorne 17:44:41;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringBuilder format = new StringBuilder();
   format.append(hora.substring(0, 2)).
   append(":").append(hora.substring(2, 4)).
   append(":").append(hora.substring(4, 6));
   System.out.println("Hora: " +format);
```

Consegui dessa forma formatar a hora que matcher me retornava